# How to loop a wav file using PortAudio?

Tags: portaudio, libsndfile

Using PortAudio and SndFile to read WAV file content, writing directly into the output stream to play the sound is doable as in the sample `wavplayer.c` [here](https://github.com/hosackm/wavplayer/blob/master/src/wavplay.c), but does anyone know how to make the sound loops infinitely until we close the stream?

```
static
int
callback
    (const void                     *input
    ,void                           *output
    ,unsigned long                   frameCount
    ,const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo
    ,PaStreamCallbackFlags           statusFlags
    ,void                           *userData
    )
{
    float           *out;
    callback_data_s *p_data = (callback_data_s*)userData;
    sf_count_t       num_read;

    out = (float*)output;
    p_data = (callback_data_s*)userData;

    /* clear output buffer */
    memset(out, 0, sizeof(float) * frameCount * p_data->info.channels);

    /* read directly into output buffer */
    num_read = sf_read_float(p_data->file, out, frameCount * p_data->info.channels);
    
    /*  If we couldn't read a full frameCount of samples we've reached EOF */
    if (num_read < frameCount)
    {
        return paComplete;
    }
    
    return paContinue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at the same time posting the question here, I sought help from the code owners and they replied with a perfect solution:

> As it's written, the stream will close at the end of the file but this
> doesn't have to happen. When the end of file is reached you could use
> sf_seek(p_data->file, 0, SF_SEEK_SET) to rewind back to the beginning
> of the file.
>
> For creating a breaking event, you could add a member done int; to
> callback_data_s and initialize it to 0. Then when you'd like the break
> to occur you could set it to 1. Then inside the callback you just
> check whether p_data->done == 1 and exit.